# Can I use yellow text on a white background to indicate warning? (Contrast checker)

Tags: usability, gui-design, interaction-design, user-behavior, interface

I am designing an app targeted towards an older audience (age 65+) so my app needs to have high contrast to be visible. I am using a contrast checker and according to WCAG standards, any yellow does not meet the 4.5:1 recommended contrast level. The closest yellow I can find is this, which to me does not look like a typical "warning" yellow that people might see on a stoplight or a green->yellow->red rating scale:[image]

Is there an alternative to using the color yellow as a warning? (Orange works better, but still not as good according to these standards) Can I add something to the yellow text (dropshadow, outline, etc) to make it contrast more?

Comment: why don't use a yellow background and a darker color for text? It's easier for accessibility and also more common than white background

Comment: @Devin The white background is the default background of our app in general. So the only way I can add a yellow background is to put a small rectangle/pill shape background and the text on top. Similar to how the "Pass" text in the image I posted has a green pill background with white text. I was hoping to avoid this kind of UI because I feel it doesn't fit with the rest of our design, but it is always an option

Comment: "...yellow background is to put a small rectangle/pill shape background and the text on top." —just like a road warning sign. I expect I'd give it a small black edge to push the yellow shape off the white background.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles Thats a fair point. I tried to solve this with just text color, but it seems that adding a background is not that bad of an idea. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the color you have chosen does not match the contact, you have several options:

- **Change the shade of yellow**

Use a darker version of yellow that passes the contrast test. Also, don't forget to check what is the minimum text size and weight you can use with this color.

[image]

- **Use background**

It is not necessary that the text should be yellow in order to convey some idea to the user. You can use standard dark text on a yellow background. In addition, if you add a couple more visual elements in the same color (labels, icons ..), this will further improve the perception of your design and thought.
[image]

- **Change hue**

Try changing the color from yellow to orange. In most cases, this color intuitively replaces yellow and can be used to indicate warnings, benchmarks, attention messages, etc.

[image]